# $x = c + (\lfloor \frac{y}{m} \rfloor \times m) - y$ resulting in negative number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

```
(x + y) mod m = c
or
(x + y) - (floor((x + y)/m) * m) = c
```

This should be reversible if x is smaller or equal to m
so my try is:

```
x = c + (floor(y/m) * m) - y
```

Now here is the problem: Sometimes I get negative numbers and I have to say $x = x + m$.

Example:

```
m = 255, x = 240, y = 111

c = 240 + 1111 mod 255
c = 76
```

Now I should be able to get $x = 240$ if I know $y$, $m$ and $c$

```
x = 76 + (floor(1111/255)*255) - 1111
x = 76 + (4 * 255) - 1111
x = 76 - 91
x = -15
```

Now $-15$ isn't what I wanted to get but $x = 255 - 15$; $x = 240$.

I don't know why and when that happens. I don't see any reasonable explanation here but there has to be one.

Edit:

Since the result is off by m I think the problem is in floor(y/m).

This is where it starts to spit out negative values:

```
x = m - (y - (floor(y/m) * m))
```

If $\frac{y}{m} = \lfloor \frac{y}{m} \rfloor$ then it is not going to give any negative values.

Comment: Is this actually modular arithmetic? If so, your notation is very poor. Or are you using "mod" as a binary operator on integers, meaning the remainder when the first parameter is divided by the second? And if that is the case, how do you handle the second parameter negative? (Different computer languages handle that differently.) Is that second equation of yours basically giving your definition of "mod"?

Comment: Your right about modular arithmetic I just thrown some tags on it because I have no clue which tag is appropriate here, thanks for the heads up. Numbers are handled as floating point and or whatever the windows-calculator and my paper uses. And yes I am using "mod" as a binary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is actually correct, since I noticed it's just your order of operations getting mixed up. In your example, you actually calculated:

```
m = 255, x = 240, y = 1111
c = (240 + 1111) mod 255
c = 76
```

To obtain the correct value for c, make sure you do the mod operation first..

```
c = 240 + (1111 mod 255)
c = 331
```

Now to check if we can indeed find the original x using your equation:

```
x = 331 + (floor(1111/255)*255) - 1111
x = 331 + (4 * 255) - 1111
x = 331 - 91
x = 240
```

What happened is that you ended up calculating (x+y) mod m = c, 
is calculating x + (y mod m) = c what you intended instead? I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works except that I need c <= m thats why i am calculating x + y before mod. This is results in c <= 2m.
I already can get the right value try x = 20 instead. That it works doing it that way is still an interesting fact.

Comment: Now that I can vote you get one. You definitely deserve it the answer helped me understanding the problem what is more important then solving it in this case (for me at least).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dr C i know that the revers-function actually belongs to

```
x + (y mod m) = c
```

not to

```
(x + y) mod m = c
```

The proper if not mathematically perfect revers-function is:

```
x = c + (floor(y/m) * m) - y
if x <= 0 then
    x = x + m
end
```

(using lua syntax here, I don't know a mathematical equivalent)

The negative values are because the mod-function "jumps" from m
to 1 (or m - 1 to 0) as x exceeds m - (y - (floor(y/m) * m)).
Because only the "jump" of the mod-function "breaks" the original
revers-function it seems to work (and works when y/m == floor(y/m)
because the "jump" is outside the range of the function (x <= m))
for some numbers.